# printf() prints the correct int value written to a pointer, but not the correct double value written to another. Why is that?

Tags: c, pointers, stack, printf, strict-aliasing

I tried declaring two variables,one of type `int *` and one of type `double *` and assigned each their addresses,but assignment by de-reference and printing displays correct value of `int` but prints `0.0` for double.why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *x;
    x = (int *)&x;
    *x = 3;
    //print val of pointer
    printf("%d\n", x);

    double *y;
    y = (double *)&y;
    *y = 4.0;
    printf("%lf\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In both cases you're invoking **undefined behaviour** - you can't expect anything sensible to happen.

Comment: Where did you dream up that from?

Comment: "why is that?" It's because the code is nonsense and does nothing meaningful. Pondering the behavior of nonsense code is not meaningful either. You cannot learn anything from this code, except that it is bad. Move on and study something useful instead.

Comment: @MartinJames I saw it in a stackoverflow nightmare where i was downvoted 3 times :):)

Comment: I think the question is interesting and sufficiently clear. There is no close reason "insane code" ;-). What question could be clearer, in fact, than asking "why does my program whose complete source code is below produce output x?" And UB or not, the reason can be perfectly clearly shown.  *Many* questions on SO are far inferior. Vote to ropen.

Comment: This is common issue - variable reference is declared but not initialized. It should be explained in the answer. I can answer myself but this is about opening the question. It should be reopened.

Comment: @Alex  I do not think anything is uninitialized here. The pointers `x` and `y` are made to point to their own memory: after `x = (int *)&x;`, `x` holds its own address. (That is weird, and generally not doable without strong-arming the type system.) Writing to `*x` therefore also changes `x`, i.e. changes where `x`  points to (the OP writes something which isn't an address, so he ends up with an illegal pointer value; accessing `*x` again would crash). So all "references" (i.e. pointers) are initialized, however crudely. Btw, the question has been re-opened.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I agree and that's the point of the question - it is not initialized. Actually it is initialized with whatever garbage was in this memory location and developers have to understand and knowledge it. That's the reason I wanted this question to be reopened.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Neither x nor y are initialized "with whatever garbage was in this memory location" (*which* location?). They are initialized (well, it is assigned to them after defining them) with the well-defined address they themselves *have* (**not** the -- undefined -- address they *point to*).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider You provided an excellent answer and I'm surprised by this comment. Pointer is the place in memory (in some location) which has address of another memory (point to). Pointer always exists. It is in memory and allocated. What is in this memory is not defined unless you initialize pointer value (good address in the memory of pointer itself). That's what people misunderstood, Again, your example shows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boy, that's the weirdest piece of code I have seen lately ...

Anyway if you really want to figure out what is going on throughout the code, the best way to do it would be to step through it with a debugger. Here's how it works on my machine:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400535: file test.c, line 6.
(gdb) run
...

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:6
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
6           x = (int *)&x;
(gdb) n
7           *x = 3;
(gdb) p x
$1 = (int *) 0x7fffffffdab0
(gdb) n
9           printf("%d\n", x);
(gdb) p x
$2 = (int *) 0x7fff00000003
(gdb) n
3
12          y = (double *)&y;
(gdb) n
13          *y = 4.0;
(gdb) p y
$3 = (double *) 0x7fffffffdab8
(gdb) n
14          printf("%lf\n", y);
(gdb) p y
$4 = (double *) 0x4010000000000000
(gdb) n
0.000000
15          return 0;
(gdb)
```

Basically what you're doing is messing up with the pointers values by using themselves in the process. When doing `*x = 3;` you can see you wiped out the least significat 32 bits of `x` by writing 0x00000003 instead. After that, when you do `*y = 4.0;` you overwrite the whole pointer value with the internal double representation of `4.0`. Intuitively, the second `printf` should print `4.0`, so I guess the issue stands within `printf` itself. If you do:

```
double test;
memcpy(&test, &y, sizeof(double));
printf("%lf\n", test);
```

This will output `4.000000`.

Answer (score 2):

I get 4.0.

What you do is you re-interpret the memory allocated to store addresses (x and y) as int and double, respectively.

You do that twice: When you assign data values to the re-interpreted memory, and when you print a copy of it. The two cases are distinct.

1. Writing to memory through a pointer of incompatible type is undefined bahavior, and compilers like gcc are known to do funny things (trap or ignore the code) in such cases. There are meandering discussions about that, including a famous rant by Linus Torvalds. It may or may not work. If it works, it probably does the expected thing. (For correct code you must use a union or perform a memcpy.)

   One condition for it to work is that your data types don't need more space than the pointers. On a 32 bit architecture (and that may be a 32 bit compiler for a 64 bit Intel CPU), a double will be longer than a 4 byte address (a IEEE 754 double has 8 bytes). `*y = 4.0;` writes beyond `y`'s memory, overwriting other data on the stack. (Note that `y` points to itself, so that assigning to `*y` overwrites `y`'s own memory.)
2. Passing a pointer value as a parameter to `printf` with a conversion specification of `%d` resp. `%lf` is undefined as well. (Actually it's already undefined if the conversion specification is `%p` and the pointer value is not cast to `void *`; but that's often ignored and irrelevant on common architectures.) printf will just interpret the memory on the stack (which is a copy of the parameters) as an int resp. as a double.

In order to understand what happens let's look at the memory layout on the stack of main. I have written a program detailing it; the source is below. On my 64 bit Windows the double value of 4.0 gets printed alright; the pointer variable `y` is large enough to hold the bytes of a double, and all 8 bytes are copied to printf's stack. But if the pointer size is only 4 bytes, only those 4 bytes will be copied to printf's stack, which are all 0, and the bytes beyond that stack will contain memory from earlier operations, or arbitrary values, for example 0 ;-), which printf will read in an attempt to decode a double.

Here is an inspection of the stack on a 64 bit architecture during the various steps. I have bracketed the pointer declarations with two sentinel variables `declStart` and `declEnd`, so that I could see where the memory  is. I would assume that the program would run with minor changes on a 32 bit architecture as well. Try it and tell us what you see!

Update: It runs on ideone, which appears to have 4 byte addresses. The double version doesn't print 0.0 but some arbitrary value, likey because of stack garbage behind the 4 address bytes. Cf. https://ideone.com/TJAXli.

[image]

The program for the output above is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dumpMem(void *start, int numBytes)
{
    printf("memory at %p:", start);
    char *p = start;
    while((unsigned long)p%8){ p--;  numBytes++;}   // align to 8 byte boundary
    for(int i=0; i<numBytes; i++) 
    {
        if( i%8 == 0 ) printf("\nAddr %p:", p+i);
        printf(" %02x", (unsigned int) (p[i] & 0xff));
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int len;        // static allocation, protect them from stack overwrites
char *from, *to;

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int    declStart = 0xaaaaaaaa; // marker
    int             *x = (int *)   0xbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb;
    double          *y = (double *)0xcccccccccccccccc;
    unsigned int    declEnd = 0xdddddddd;   // marker

    printf("Addr. of x: %p,\n      of y: %p\n", &x, &y);

    // This is all UB because the pointers are not
    // belonging to the same object. But it should
    // work on standard architectures.
    // All calls to dumpMem() therefore are UB, too.
    
    // Thinking of it, I'd be hard-pressed to find 
    // any defined behavior in this program.
    if( &declStart < &declEnd ) 
    {
        from = (char *)&declStart;
        to = (char *)&declEnd + sizeof(declEnd);
    }
    else
    {
        from = (char *)&declEnd;
        to = (char *)&declStart + sizeof(declStart);
    }
    len = to - from;

    printf("len is %d\n", len);
    printf("Memory after initializations:\n");
    dumpMem(from, len);

    x = (int *)&x;
    printf("\nMemory after assigning own address %p to x/*x: \n", &x);
    dumpMem(from, len);
    
    *x = 3;
    printf("\nMemory after assigning 3 to x/*x: \n");
    dumpMem(from, len);

    //print val of pointer
    printf("x as long: %d\n", (unsigned long)x);

    y = (double *)&y;
    *y = 4.0;
    printf("\nMemory after assigning 4.0 to y/*y: \n");
    dumpMem(from, len);

    printf("y as float: %f\n", y);
    printf("y as double: %lf\n", y);
    printf("y as unsigned int: 0x%x\n", y);
    printf("y as unsigned long: 0x%lx\n", y);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very good explanation and that's why I wanted this question to be reopened and answered properly.